# installing Realm through Cocoa pods fail

Tags: realm, cocoapods

i m getting this error below while installing Realm through Cocoapods . What's the problem here? I rarely get answers on stack overflow although everybody advices here but I hope this time I can get an answer !

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3tpa.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may not be getting answers due to the question content. Tagging questions with your development environment (Swift? Flutter?) is helpful. Also, including XCode and Cocoapods versions would be good. Include your podfile so we know what pods are being used. Then the last important thing is that code and errors should be included as *text* in questions. That will allow future readers to locate it (screen shots are not searchable). The last thing is the links can break, and if that happens, the question won't make any sense. Update and we'll take a look!

Comment: Two other things you may want to review so you can write excellent questions [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)